# Obtain index of random element from json array in JMeter Json Path Post Processor

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I have strange case for jmeter. Imagine that we have an json array with elements like this:

```
{
  "id"  : 123456,
  "name": "TEST"
}
```

So I want to get random element from array that has `id`. For this case I use `Json Path PostProcessor` with expression like this `$.elements[?(@.id)]`

But for some reasons I need an index of this element. So I can create `BeanShellPostProcessor` generate random index and then use same `Json Path PostProcessor` with expression like this `$.elements[${PARAM_ElementIndex}]`. 
But in some cases this array can be empty  and `Json Path PostProcessor` wil fail with exception like this:

`jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONPostProcessor: Error processing JSON content in PARAM_ResumeId, message:No results for path: $['elements'][0]['id']`

So may be someone can suggest any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend use Groovy instead of Beanshell as:

- Well-behaved Groovy scripts can be compiled into bytecode therefore performance will be much higher
- Groovy has built-in JSON support

So given you have JSON Response like:

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "id": 123456,
      "name": "TEST"
    },
    {
      "id": 7890,
      "name": "TEST2"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can extract random ID along with its index using the following example Groovy code in the JSR223 PostProcessor:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(response)

int size = json.elements.size

if (size > 0){
    def randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(size)
    def value = json.elements.get(randomIndex).id
    log.info('Index: ' + randomIndex)
    log.info('Value: ' + value)
}
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy JSON JMeter]

References:

- [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)